# does google v8 support the keyword "let"? not in node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I need to use google v8 in my project.But I find that if I use keyword "let" in javascript code ,it cannot be compiled.
such as " let x=10 "..

I know that Node.js can use "let" by argument "--hanmony".But I just use V8 in my project, do not use Node.js .
so,I want to konw that: can V8 support the keyword "let"？if it support it,what i need to do?

ps. "const" is also the new element in  ECMA6,but V8 can support it whitout problems. so I guess V8 can support "let" too, just need to do something?isn't it?

my English is poor,and I need your help very much,thk.

Remarks：I only use V8 in my C++ project whitout Node.js. SO, I want to get some help about V8, not Node.js. thanks again

Comment: Try with the `--harmony` flag. `node --harmony someScript.js`

Comment: How are you calling V8? Surely it has some flags for harmony support, as node can work with it. Btw, if you're not asking about using [tag:node.js], then please don't tag your question with it.

Comment: You could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile ES6 to ES5 if you want a more consistent experience (I don't know how much of ES6 V8 has implemented so far).

Comment: https://iojs.org/en/index.html has it